# loop in react when updating status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is in charge of performing a network request using `fetch`. The API response will be shown on cards within the component.
I have defined the structure of the response in the state as `movimientos`. But when updating the state inside `filtrarDatos` function with the response, an infinite loop is created and `fetch` requests are performed infinitely.

Here is my code:

```jsx
export class Datepicker extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           startDate: "",
           endDate: "",
           focusedInput: "",
           movimientos: {}
       }
   }

   filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString) {
       if (startDateString !== '' && endDateString !== '') {
           const empresa = {
               FECHA_INICIAL: startDateString,
               FECHA_FINAL: endDateString
           };

           const options = {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               body: JSON.stringify(empresa)

           }

           fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/movimiento/filtrarfecha', options)
               .then((res) => res.json())
               .then((data) => {
                   const { movimientos } = data
                   console.log({ movimientos })
                   this.setState({ movimientos })
               })
               .catch((err) => console.log(err))
       }
   }

   render() {
       const endDateString = this.state.endDate && this.state.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T13:47:14.985+00:00";
       const startDateString = this.state.startDate && this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T13:47:14.985+00:00";

       return (
           <div className="DatePicker">
               <DateRangePicker
                   startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
                   endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
                   onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                   focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
                   onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                   endDatePlaceholderText={"Fecha inicial"}
                   startDatePlaceholderText={"Fecha final"}
                   displayFormat={"DD/MM/YYYY"}
                   numberOfMonths={1}
                   isOutsideRange={() => false}
                   showClearDates={true}
               />
               {this.filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString)}
           </div>
       )
   }
}
```

To be more clear the error is in the following part of the code, if I comment on the status update the program works correctly and only makes a single request. I am new to react and I cannot understand what is happening.

```
.then((data) => {
    const { movimientos } = data
    console.log({ movimientos })
    this.setState({ movimientos })
})
```

This is a screenshot of my console during infinite network requests
[image: console screenshot]

Comment: You should add the `fetch` call inside `componentDidMount()` life cycle method. It is recommended to place the API call here. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Comment: Yes, @mukesh.kumar is right! Hi added an example in my answer, showing how to do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its happening because `this.filtrarDatos` is being called after each re-render (state changes), creating a infinite loop (change data, render, change data, rend...)

You can move the `{ this.filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString) }` to `componentDidMount`:

1. Remove `{ this.filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString) }`
2. Add this `lifecycle` function, after `constructor`:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const endDateString = this.state.endDate && this.state.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T13:47:14.985+00:00";
  const startDateString = this.state.startDate && this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T13:47:14.985+00:00";

  this.filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `{this.filtrarDatos(startDateString, endDateString)}` in your render body, then in this method you update state, so it creates an infinite loop because react rerender your component after state changes.